# If compiler of Haskell always needs polymorphic parameters of polymorphic functions to be specified with "::Int",why "show 2" is legal

Tags: class, function, haskell, show, polymorphism

If we type `show 2`,then we will get "2".But the question is show satisfies `show :: Show a => a -> String`,and `2` is polymorphic, if unfortunately `show 2::Int` differs from `show 2::Integer` we'd have to write `show 2::Int` and `show 2::Integer` rather than simply `show 2`.

I refuse to assume that the compiler is enough intelligent to know when `(A a)=>show a`,all current instances of A are of Show, gives the same result, we needn't to specify `show a::X` and when `(A a)=>show a`,all current instances of A are of Show, gives different results, we have to specify `show a::X`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to defaulting rules. So `show 2` is actually `show (2::Integer)`. You can read this in haskell 2010 report [here in section 4.3.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3).

To answer your second question, compiler is not intelligent enough. It happens due to type defaulting.

You can check

```
 number = 2
```

In ghci

```
*Main> :t number 
 number :: Integer
```

Now your custom default signature

```
 default (Int)
 number = 2
```

In ghci

```
*Main> :t number
number :: Int
```

You can read about when a type is defaultable in the document I referenced.

Comment: Thanks, your answer also applies to why when Data.Typeable imported "typeOf 2=Integer".